# Configuring Server log file

Tags: tomcat

We've developped an application that consumes several adapters. Each adapter produce several logs via WL.Logger.info, error,... methods. Typically these are all written to the application server's messages.log file.

I'm wondering how can we configure the target file of the logs on the server.

Comment: I'm not clear... You want to configure the file where your app's logs are written? And in which server?

Comment: The server is a Tomcat. Currently logs are being writen to the default server log file, catalina.out. We'd like to configure worklight in order to write logs in a separated log file, like worklight.log

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a complete guide from Tomcat on how to configure application logs output (file to write, location, log level...):

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/logging.html